# What comes after seconds?

Tags: trigonometry, math-history

Angles can be measured in different ways. For example, one can measure angles in degrees/minutes/seconds. So $1^\circ$ is divded into $60$ min. and $1$ min is divided into $60$ sec. That way a tenth of a minute is $6$ seconds. Are seconds divided into anything? If one has for example a tenth of a second, is this just $0.1 $ sec. ?

Comment: As noted in [the Subdivisions section of Wikipedia's "Degree" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#Subdivisions), one *can* continue with 60ths of 60ths of 60ths of a degree, etc. With that system, one-tenth of a second would be 6 "thirds" ($0.1^{\prime\prime} = 6^{\prime\prime\prime}$), and one-tenth of a "third" would be 6 "fourths", and so on. It should be noted that the international standard (ISO 6709) for geo-coordinates favors decimal degrees over even using minutes and seconds; sexagesimal subdivisions would seem to be falling out of favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Converting comment to answer, as requested.]

As noted in [the Subdivisions section of Wikipedia's "Degree" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#Subdivisions), one can continue with 60ths of 60ths of 60ths of a degree, etc. With that system, one-tenth of a second would be 6 "thirds" ($0.1^{\prime\prime}=6^{\prime\prime\prime}$), and one-tenth of a "third" would be 6 "fourths", and so on.

It should be mentioned that the international standard ([ISO 6709](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709)) for geo-coordinates favors decimal degrees over even using minutes and seconds. Sexagesimal subdivisions would seem to be falling out of favor.

Answer (score 1):

1/60 of a degree is actually called a minute of arc or **arcmin**. It is informally called minute. 1/60 of 1 arcmin is called **arcsecond** Standard SI Prefixes can be used to describe smaller units of angular measurement, for instance, **centiarcsecond** is 1/100 of an arcsecond.